# Why is this false alert(5>3>2) in javascript?

Tags: javascript

In javascript `alert(5>3>2)` this return as false. I don't know what is the explanation. This was ask during my interview here in Cebu, Philippines. Can you explain why?

Comments are highly appreciated.. Thank you.

Comment: Think of it this way ~ `(5 > 3) > 2`

Comment: This should help you with understanding the rules of implicit coercion https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/types%20%26%20grammar/ch4.md#chapter-4-coercion

Comment: Thank you for the link. It helps me a lot.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The interpreter evaluates this expression like this

```
5 > 3 > 2
(5 > 3) > 2
true > 2
1 > 2
false
```

Answer (score 1):

Its because of how javascript engine works. Check out operator associativity for < or >. It compares left to right.
  5>3>2 javascript translates to true > 2. true has value 1, so it then compares 
1 > 2, which is false.

I hope it helps.